# Invalid Column In SQL Query

Tags: subquery

```
select 
  university_cars_video_kroenke.dbo.car_customer.cus_first,
  university_cars_video_kroenke.dbo.car_customer.cus_last,
  (
    select COUNT(university_cars_video_kroenke.dbo.car_customer.cus_id)
    from university_cars_video_kroenke.dbo.car_purchases 
    where university_cars_video_kroenke.dbo.car_customer.cus_id = university_cars_video_kroenke.dbo.car_purchases.cus_id
  )
  from university_cars_video_kroenke.dbo.car_customer
```

(edited for clarity)

```
    select 
        customer.cus_first, 
        customer.cus_last, 
        (select 
            COUNT(customer.cus_id) 
            from purchases 
            where customer.cus_id = purchases.cus_id )
        from customer
```

My error message is

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Column
'university_cars_video_kroenke.dbo.car_customer.cus_first' 
is invalid in the select list because it is not contained 
in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

I just want a count of records the cus_id is the same in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want a count of records the cus_id is the same in both tables.

Something like the following should work.

```
  SELECT
    A.cus_id,
    count(A.cus_id)
  FROM
    university_cars_video_kroenke.dbo.car_customer AS A,
    university_cars_video_kroenke.dbo.car_purchases AS B
  WHERE
    A.cus_id = B.cus_id
```